# How broad is the term statistical summary?

Tags: terminology

I am wondering how broad is the term "statistical summary". For example, can a set of inferential statistics, descriptive statistics, along with both parametric and non-parametric density estimation, be considered a statistical summary? If a "statistical summary" doesn't encapsulate this whole set of abstractions, is there a better term?

Comment: In Minitab, the 'describe' command will get you the five number summary (min, Q1, Med, Q3, Max) plus mean and standard deviation; other descriptive statistics: skewness, kurtosis, etc. are optional. A library in R has a similar function. The 'summary' function in R applied to a vector of observations displays the 5-nr summary and the mean, but 'sd', 'var', etc. allow computation of other descriptive statistics. I think something like that is what most statisticians consider a summary of data. Confidence intervals and tests vary so much with distribution that they might not be included.

Comment: There is no definition of "statistical summary". It means whatever you want it to mean

Comment: I would not be surprised at a statistical summary including bivariate results such as correlations or graphical results such as smoothed curves. So, it's as broad or narrow as collective custom or personal taste makes it. The point is usually to give broad features and not to include any report or comment on  detail or fine structure, but that's not a rule.

Comment: I acknowledge graphical representations of data as a form of "statistical summary:" that is, the summary needn't be just a collection of numbers or intervals. It could be a smooth of a time series, for instance; or a contour plot of bivariate data; or a choropleth map; *etc.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is a term for which there is a widely accepted definition. So, unless your specific field has a commonly used meaning for the term, you can probably use it flexibly.

If a document had this heading, I would not find it particularly weird to see what you described in your example under this heading. I would probably normally prefer "Results" or "Summary of results", but if there are multiple types of results, some further distinction might be needed. E.g. if there are qualtitative results from interviews, as well as results from statistical analyses for some other research, then perhaps "Summary of quantitative results", "Results of quantitative analyses", "Results of statistical analyses", "Statistical summary" or any other similar term is a reasonable heading for a section describing solely the latter type of results.

Answer (score 1):

Below is Minitab's 'Graphical Summary' of 100 observations chosen from the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\, \sigma = 10.)$ It gives more extensive results than those from `describe` as mentioned in my Comment.

[This summary seems to have been planned with the possibility of normal data in mind. It automatically includes a test of normality and confidence intervals for mean and standard deviation assume normal data--even if data fail the normality test.]

Several other software packages
give similar information, but not always labeled as a 'summary' and not always with the same list of information. In SAS, `proc univariate` gives several pages of output.

This gives you a general idea, but I am not aware of any *standard definition*
of the word 'summary'.

[image]

*Note:* The normal density curve superimposed on the histogram estimates the population mean $\mu$ by the sample mean $\bar X$ and the population standard deviation $\sigma$ by the sample standard deviation $S.$ If the data were from an exponential distribution the normal curve would tend to be a poor fit to the histogram, and the confidence intervals for mean and standard deviation would be inappropriate.

Comment: The fact that a software package calls something "summary" does not make it the definition of the term.

Comment: As far as I know there is no US or international body which sets formal rules. A summary means whatever someone feels it does, although for a class, journal or work there might be a formal rule for this.

Comment: @asdf Of course not. Nevertheless, choices of software developers do have great influence (perhaps too great) on how many people learn to summarize data. This may be especially true with SAS.

Comment: @asdf Although you are correct, the use of a term by a software developer is *prima facie* evidence of one of its possible meanings.  The more widely adopted the software is, the stronger is the evidence that this meaning is "accepted" or widely understood.  In extreme cases (the GIS community is a good example), the principal software developers *determine* the meanings of terms--regardless of any original or widely accepted meanings!--because their users automatically employ the software's terminology. (I suspect various ML communities may offer similar examples.)

Comment: @whuber Right, but the question does not refer to what "summary" means in a certain context, but rather about how broad the term is. Since there is no standard, the term is as broad as you want it to be

Comment: @asdf I see.  But I suspect this reply was offered more in the spirit of investigating how people actually use the term *statistical summary* in an empirical effort to establish a more useful answer than that.